# Is zero multiplied by does not exist equal to zero?

Tags: limits, infinity

I watched a youtube video explaining how to get

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \left( \frac{\sin{(2x)}}{x} \right)$

He applied the properties of limits such that

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) \cdot \lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \sin{(2x)}$

In which, after evaluation,

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = 0$

and

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \sin{(2x)}$ = DNE.

So, it went

$ 0 \cdot DNE$

Is this always the case, especially for transcendental functions like trigonometric functions?

If $ 0 \cdot DNE$ can be equal to zero, then why is $ 0 \cdot \infty$ indeterminate?

I understand that infinity is not a number but a concept and there's no way to determine $ 0 \cdot \infty$ to be anything else. But why is DNE a special case if it is not a number too?

Thanks!

Comment: The second deduction from top is forbidden! We don't allow to do such a thing!

Comment: Compare to: $\;\lim_{x \to \infty} \sin 2x = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{x} 
 \cdot x \sin 2x\right)=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} 
 \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty} x \sin 2x = 0 \cdot DNE = 0\,$. No, it does not work that way.

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong. The assertion$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigl(f(x)g(x)\bigr)=\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\right)\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)\right)\tag1$$holds when both limits of the RHS of $(1)$ exist, but that's not the case here. However, it is true that if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ and if $g$ is a bounded function, then $\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigl(f(x)g(x)\bigr)=0$, and this can be used here.

Comment: Is this applicable to all bounded functions? But how about
$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \left(\frac{\cot{(x)}}{x} \right)$? It is also equal to zero after using a calculator. But I think cotangent is not a bounded function?

Comment: Please have a deep look at what is written above. I see, you would have the answer. ;-)

Comment: Yes, it works to all bounded functions. Otherwise, I would not have written what I wrote. And actually, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\cot x}x$ does not exist.